# How to send data from /dev/pts/X to /dev/pts/Y?

Tags: linux, shell

I've opened /dev/pts/X and /dev/pts/Y and i want to send some data from X to Y, through **write command** i can send, **but** i don't know terminal number, is there anyway to get terminal number and send data to that terminal(X to Y)?

Comment: Check `who` and `wall` commands. Alternative to wall command is -   `echo "your data" | write <user>`

Comment: here i have to give terminal number(/dev/pts/12) means to which terminal i want to write. But i'm asking a programmatic to get the terminal number Eg:/dev/pts/12